# Calculating % of only each group by value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have query below as

```
select month, type, count(*) / sum(count(*)) over() as ratio
from 
(
    select
    ID,
    date_trunc('month',to_date(hour,'YYYYMMDDHH24')) as month,
    timestamp,
    from tbl 
where hour between '2021060100' and '2021073123'
and (type IN('A','B') or type is null)) 
where type IN('A','B')
group by 1,2;
""")


Current output:
month     | type | ratio
2021-06-01    A      .60
2021-06-01    B      .05
2021-07-01    A      .30
2021-07-01    B      .05


Desired Output:
month     | type | ratio
2021-06-01    A      .60
2021-06-01    B      .40
2021-07-01    A      .85
2021-07-01    B      .15
```

Where I want desired output to show % of only that month, am I missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to partition by month in your `over`:

```
  select month, type, count(*) / sum(count(*)) over(partition by month)
```